# Firebase - Update large datasets

Tags: firebase

I'm planning to use Firebase instead of mySql in a on-going project.
Firebase looks good, but I can't figure out how to update values in large datasets.

In SQL, INSERT, UPDATE OR DELETE can update a table of millions of entries in few ms.
The only way I found to do the same operation with Firebase is to loop through each element of a collection and call "set" or "update" within the loop (after verifying some conditions).
With only a few thousands of entries, this already takes a couple of minutes!

Is there any other solution? Or Is Firebase not suitable for bulk operations in large datasets? (which I would find very limiting)

Comment: Aside from multi-location updates (see [here](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html) and [here](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html)) your options are limited. This is normal in NoSQL databases. I recommend reading [NoSQL Data Modelling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/). Aside from that, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you need to update many records regularly, something is wrong in your data model.

Comment: Yes, it might be a XY problem! I see NoSQL as a flexible data store that can adapt well while my app requirements evolve.
For example what if I have a chat app with 1M rooms and I want to add an attribute "color" for the rooms. Will I have to write 1M times?

Comment: If you want to update 1 million records, there will have to be 1 million writes. That's the same for any data store. I'd also like to congratulate you on the success of your chat app. :-)   The difference is that Firebase doesn't offer a single command to do this, where in SQL you could fire a query-based `UPDATE`. But the operation on the disk is equally expensive. In NoSQL, you either prevent this type of nulk update (why would you write the same value to 1M nodes?) or perform it in batches (for example as the rooms are updated/opened).